# C++ an object with its own method?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm sorry, this is probably a stupid question. I am obviously misunderstanding something fundamental about object oriented programming. I am used to C and am now trying to use C++.

I have some buttons in a class called Button. Each button does something different. What I *want* to write is something like this:

```
Button button1;
Button button2;
...
void button1::onClick () {
    ...
}
void button2::onClick () {
    ...
}
```

But that does not work ("button 1 is not a class, namespace or enumeration" - yes I know!). I know I could just make a separate class for each button:

```
class button1_class : public Button {
public:
     void onclick () {
        ...
     }
} button1;
class button2_class : public Button {
     ...
}
```

But to me it 'feels' wrong to make a class when I know for sure it will only have one member.

I'm using Agui, a GUI library for Allegro 5.

EDIT

Thanks for the responses. While they are all helpful and (I think) all valid answers, nobody has actually said yet "no you cannot have an object with its own unique method because..."

So for example, if object1 is of type ObjectClass then object1 is not allowed to have a method (a member function) that is unique to object1, but rather possesses *only* the methods that are defined as part of ObjectClass. Is that right?
I'm sorry I did not include my actual use case. I was kind of more interested in just getting my head around OOP so that I can do it properly on my own.

EDIT2
Looking at the responses in more detail I suppose it is possible with lambda expressions, it's just not in the way I imagined it. Thanks again

Comment: A set of similar classes, each with only one member function of the same name, but different functionality to the others does not appear to be a good design.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 7):

The natural C++ way is to do as vsoftco explained, with virtuals and inheritance.

However, if your `Button` class has already everything needed, and the only thing that changes between the buttons is the unique (trhow-away) action to be performed, you may want to consider this alternative:

```
class Button {
    function<void()>  f; 
public: 
    Button(function<void()> mf) : f(mf) {}
    void onClick() { f();  }
};
```

This variant of your class uses a **[`function`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/function/)** object (think of it as a kind of  function pointer but much more flexible to use).

You can then use it with **[lambda-functions](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html)** as in this example:

```
int main(int ac, char**av) 
{
    Button button1([&]() { cout << "Hello 1!\n"; });
    Button button2 ([]() { cout << "Hello 2!\n"; });

    button1.onClick();
    button2.onClick();
}
```

Comment: nice way of doing it! +1

Comment: Nice answer, I was about to post the same idea.  But why the capture all by reference in `button1`'s lambda?

Answer (score 3):

If the buttons have different functionalities, best thing to do is to create a `BaseButton` class in which you mark the `onclick()` as `virtual` (or make it pure virtual, which will make `BaseButton` an abstract class), then derive each other button from `BaseButton`, making sure to override `onclick()` in each derived class. You then need to use the buttons via a reference or pointer to a `BaseButton`, this way you achieve what is called "polymorphic behaviour".

For example:

```
class BaseButton
{
    virtual void onclick() {/*implement here or declare pure virtual*/}
};

class RedButton: public BaseButton /* overrides only onclick */
{
    void onclick() override { /*specific implementation for Red Buttons */}
};

class ShinyRedButton: public RedButton /* overrides only onclick */
{
    void onclick() override { /*specific implementation for Shiny Red Buttons */}

};
```

then use it like (C++14 smart pointers)

```
std::unique_ptr<BaseButton> bb = new ShinyRedButton;
bb->onclick(); // will pick up the "right" ShinyRedButton::onclick()` function
```

Comment: I disagree that a new type for each button is right here. Unless these are categories of button that have tightly bound behaviours and will be re-used often. It depends on usage.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think it depends on the exact scenario. From OPs question it was not entirely clear: "*Each button does something different*". If only `onclick()` is different, then yes, you're right, you should pass the functionality to the lambda.

Comment: Yeah like I said it depends. Hence no "-1" :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in many ways.

1. Using a `Button` class where button objects have a pointer to methods that are invoked `onClick`. In C you would do this using a callback and you can also do it that way in C++:

   ```
   class Button {
       using funType = void(void);
   public:
       Button(funType* callback) : function(callback) { }
       void onClick() { function(); }
   private:
       funType* function;
   };
   ```

   However do take note that function pointers are error prone, can't really be inlined by the compiler, and should generally be avoided. This method also works with capture-less lambdas.

   ```
   Button red([] { std::cout << "Red button\n"; });
   Button green(&green_button_function);
   ```
2. Creating different `Button` objects with different `onClick` methods on the fly. C++ has a mechanism to do this called templates:

   ```
   template <class Fun>
   class Button {
   public:
       Button(Fun f) : functor(f) { }
       void onClick() { functor(); }
   private:
       Fun functor;
   };

   template <class Fun>
   Button<Fun> make_button(Fun f) { return Button<Fun>(f); }
   ```

   I am omitting details such as references on purpose here.
   You could then use the `Button` class with callbacks as well as lambdas in the following way:

   ```
   auto green = make_button([] { std::cout << "Green button pressed!\n"; });
   auto red = make_button(&red_button_function);
   ```

   You need to use `auto` with this method because otherwise you would have to specify the type of the *functionality* by hand, which is not possible e.g. for lambda objects.
3. Using polymorphism as shown by vsoftco, where you create separate classes for each `Button` functionality. Or you can make a `ButtonAction` abstract class to which `Button` has a reference. Then you implement different functionalities in different classes, but stay with one `Button` class. This is known as the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

   ```
   class ButtonAction {
   public:
       virtual void onClick() = 0;
   };

   class Button {
   public:
       Button(std::unique_ptr<ButtonAction> action) : 
           action_(std::move(action)) {}
       void onClick() { action_->onClick();  }
   private:
       std::unique_ptr<ButtonAction> action_;
   };

   class RedButtonAction : public ButtonAction {
       void onClick() override { red(); }
   };
   class GreenButtonAction : public ButtonAction {
       void onClick() override { green(); }
   };
   ```

   Using this method requires constructing `Button`s from `ButtonAction` `unique_ptr`s

   ```
   Button red(std::unique_ptr<ButtonAction>(new RedButtonAction));
   Button green(std::unique_ptr<ButtonAction>(new GreenButtonAction));
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You're right in that, if each button is fundamentally the same but needs different event handlers bound to it, implementing a new type for each one is not quite right.

Instead your `Button` type would have a member function that allows users to "attach" an event handler, and a member function to invoke it.

```
class Button
{
public:
    Button()
       : onClickHandler()
    {}

    void setOnClickHandler(std::function<void()> callback)
    {
       onClickHandler = callback;
    }

    friend class UI;

private:
    void onClick()
    {
       onClickHandler();
    }

    std::function<void()> onClickHandler;
};
```

Then your user does:

```
void foo()
{
   std::cout << "Some buttons do this!\n";
}

Button btn;
btn.setOnClickHandler(foo);
```

And your program's internals will set up things such that your window manager (above I've assumed that it's some class called `UI`) invokes `btn.onClick()` for you, which, since you "attached" `foo`, will end up invoking `foo`.

(In modern C++ you'd probably make use of lambda functions to tidy this up, but the above is a *simple* example to showcase the general design idea.)

In this way, you can attach different handlers to different `Button` instances, but the `Button` interface itself is stable.

This is similar to how, for example, you manipulate the DOM in JavaScript.

Comment: I am the user :)  The GUI library that I'm using has an event handler system - as Drew Dormann pointed out - using an ActionListener class which has an actionPerformed virtual method. But then I would still be defining a separate ActionListener class for every individual button. I would prefer to have the handler in the object rather than in a separate object, not least because it seems I will need to call the onclick method manually as well. But there is no getActionListener method so I wouldn't know which listener to call, given the button. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using a std::function is the key here.  You will have the virtual call overheard and potential memory allocation if your callable (lambda, function, member function) is large.  This achieves your requirements of a single type executing different callbacks without defining an class inheritance.  Also using uniform initialization makes it very convenient to construct Button class with a lambda without manually creating a constructor.

Live example:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9007c3f103f3ffe

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Button
{
  function<void()> OnClick;
};

int main()
{
  vector<Button> buttons = 
  {
      {[] { printf("Button0::OnClick()\n"); }},
      {[] { printf("Button1::OnClick()\n"); }},
      {[] { printf("Button2::OnClick()\n"); }},
  };

  for(auto&& button : buttons)
    button.OnClick();
}
```

Comment: There is no difference between "manually" creating the constructor with a member initialization list and your approach. In terms of code generation, they do the same thing (your code also generates the an implicit default constructor).

Comment: That is exactly the point.  Same result, less code.  Why do more work when you can make the compiler do it for you?  More context of the problem is required before we can discuss if limiting the generation of implicitly defined constructors / operators is required.

Comment: in general the buttons are a bit more complicated, and my belief is that encapsulation is almost always a good idea (especially since you may want to do some pre-processing of parameters passed to the constructor). For this particular example, yes I agree your scheme works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your [Agui library](https://github.com/jmasterx/Agui) supports a signaling system, with the member function `addActionListener`.

This allows you to derive a class from `agui::ActionListener` to perform the specific task intended for one or more buttons:

```
class SimpleActionListener : public agui::ActionListener
{
public:
    virtual void actionPerformed(const agui::ActionEvent &evt)
    {
        std::cout << "Button pushed" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The object above can be attached to a button's "press" action with:

```
SimpleActionListener simpleAL;
button1.addActionListener(&simpleAL);
```